# Eclipse Errors - Recommended solution/alternative

Tags: android, eclipse

After reading most of the similar questions, nothing seem to be working with regard to this message in eclipse:

Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
No repository found at http://dlssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/helios.

I tried different routes and get to this:
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

I see Android Studio is still in Beta.  And I need to update my apps with the new admob code, so what do I do now? I am stuck, any advice? Do I uninstall eclipse and reinstall?  Please I would appreciate your help.

Comment: what exactly is the error you are getting or the problem you are having?

Comment: in eclipse available software sites try using `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` instead. Note the `https:` Also remove then the `http:` ones

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu?  Are you actually using Helios?  Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu comes configured to use the Helios update site.  You've gotta go in and manually set it up to use the Indigo update site.